# How can I use only a subspec of my pod in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have my own pod where I divided it to 3 parts (Core, Network, UI) and I did that so I can use only the Network to my second target.

The `podFile` looks like this:

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'MyOwnPod', :git=>'https://....', :branch=>'subspecs'
end

target 'MyApp Extension' do
    pod 'MyOwnPod/Network', :git=>'https://....', :branch=>'subspecs'

end
```

Now in my main app I want to share a file (which use the whole pod) with the second target.
How can I use something like `import MyOwnPod/Network` instead of `import MyOwnPod` to this file so I wouldn't have a problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?